# Can I create my own element design in stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a subscription page where I want to fill card details of user.I want to use stripe elements.So I can keep my design or use the element's predefined design

Comment: Yes go to the stripe github and view their elements examples. --- then you can apply your own css via css and also via javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should largely be able to adapt Elements to work with your existing design.

You can style the containers surrounding Elements with your existing CSS. As the Elements themselves are hosted by Stripe and served within iframes, you can specify a limited set of style properties within a 'style' hash when you create Elements in your Javascript code.

See the reference here:
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#elements-create

```
var style = {
  base: {
    // Add your base input styles here. For example:
    fontSize: '16px',
    color: "#32325d",
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');
```

You can see a range of styled samples that Stripe put together here: https://stripe.github.io/elements-examples/